# the rank of a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be vector space consisting of all continuous real-valued functions defined on the closed interval $[0,1]$ (over the field of real numbers) and $T$ be linear transformation from $V$ to $V$ defined by

$$(Tf)(x) = \int_0 ^1 (3x^3 y - 5x^4 y^2) f(y)\,\mathrm dy$$

Why is $\operatorname{rank}(T) = 2$?

Comment: I would suggest using the notation $(Tf)(x)$ instead to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(f(x)) = 3x^3\int_0 ^1 yf(y) dy-5x^4\int_0^1 y^2f(y) dy$.
So all functions are mapped to $ax^3+bx^4$. Therefore the dimension of image space is 2.
But we know that rank of transformation is same as dimension of its image space.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have shown the rank is *at most* 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but we can easily exhibit $f(x)$ such that it is only $x^3$ or $x^4$ as done by copper.hat.Thank You for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $(Tf)(x) = 3x^3 \int_0^1 y f(x)dy - 5 x^4 \int_0^1 y^2 f(y)dy$, hence
$Tf \in \operatorname{sp} \{ x \mapsto x^3, x \mapsto x^4 \}$, so $\dim {\cal R} T \le 2$.

If we choose $f(x) = {2\over 3} -x$, we see $(Tf)(x) = {5 \over 36} x^4$, and if we choose $f(x) = {4\over 3} -x$, we see that $(Tf)(x) ={1 \over 24} x^3$, hence
$\dim {\cal R} T = 2$.

Comment: I am often curious why a later, slightly less complete, answer is accepted. The points are not the issue, I am interested in understanding the 'why'.